# Ignite : Can I set affinity key after pushing data?

Tags: database, key, distributed-computing, ignite, affinity

I have already pushed data from source to Ignite but I had not configured affinity key. If I configure affinity key now, will data get re-distributed or should I re-push data in ignite?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The table configuration in Ignite -- including the affinity key -- is largely immutable. In order to change the affinity key you'll need to drop and recreate the table.